# How to increment a global variable within another bash script

Tags: macos, bash, shell

Question,

I want to have a bash script that will have a global variable that can be incremented from other bash scripts.

Example:
I have a script like the following:

```
 #! /bin/bash
export Counter=0
   for SCRIPT in /Users/<user>/Desktop/*sh
    do
        $SCRIPT
    done
echo $Counter
```

That script will call all the other bash scripts in a folder and those scripts will have something like the following:

```
if [ "$Output" = "$Check" ]
    then
       echo "OK"
      ((Counter++))
```

I want it to then increment the $Counter variable if it does equal "OK" and then pass that value back to the initial batch script so I can keep that counter number and have a total at the end.

Any idea on how to go about doing that?

Comment: You'll need to use the filesystem, as child processes can't change their parents' environment.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy elaborate please how do i go about doing this

Comment: If you can't handle the increment in the main loop (it is a static increase each script) then you get to output the count to a file that the main script can read each loop or use a file that each script reads at the start and writes to at the end/etc.

Comment: ...now, on a different point, relying on filenames to determine what is or isn't a script is bad form. Better to have a dedicated directory that's nothing but, and possibly filter on whether a file has `+x` permissions. (What if someone wants to write their hook in Python? Would they still need to name it with a trailing `sh`?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Environment variables propagate in one direction only -- from parent to child. Thus, a child process cannot change the value of an environment variable set in their parent.

What you can do is use the filesystem:

```
export counter_file=$(mktemp "$HOME/.counter.XXXXXX")
for script in ~user/Desktop/*sh; do "$script"; done
```

...and, in the individual script:

```
counter_curr=$(< "$counter_file" )
(( ++counter_curr ))
printf '%s\n' "$counter_curr" >"$counter_file"
```

This isn't currently concurrency-safe, but your parent script as currently written will never call more than one child at a time.

---

An even easier approach, assuming that the value you're tracking remains relatively small, is to use the file's size as a proxy for the counter's value. To do this, incrementing the counter is as simple as this:

```
printf '\n' >>"$counter_file"
```

...and checking its value in O(1) time -- without needing to open the file and read its content -- is as simple as checking the file's size; with GNU `stat`:

```
counter=$(stat -f %z "$counter_file")
```

Note that locking may be required for this to be concurrency-safe if using a filesystem such as NFS which does not correctly implement `O_APPEND`; see [Norman Gray's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30626678/14122) (to which this owes inspiration) for a working implementation.

Comment: Im not a wiz when it comes to bash so bear with me please.... When you say $counter_file is that the file that was created in the "mktemp" section?

Comment: Correct. `mktemp` creates a unique filename, so several copies of this script running at the same time all have their own counters.

Comment: BSD systems, including OSX, don't support `stat --format=%z`.
A more portable version of the stat in the answer from @charles-duffy is:
`counter=$(stat -f %z "$counter_file")`

Comment: @adkisson, ...I'm surprised `-f` is supported either, but amending the answer to incorporate.

Answer (score 2):

You could `source` the other scripts, which means they're not running in a sub-process but "inline" in the calling script like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
export counter=0
   for script in /Users/<user>/Desktop/*sh
   do
       source "$script"
   done
echo $counter
```

But as pointed out in the comments i'd only advise to use this approach if you control the called scripts yourself. If they for example `exit` or have variables clashing with each other, bad things could happen.

Comment: This works, but is a substantial risk -- means an `exit` or `exec` inside the parent process will stop future scripts from being run.

Answer (score 1):

As described, you can't do this, since there isn't anything which corresponds to a ‘global variable’ for shell scripts.

As the comment suggests, you'll have to use the filesystem to communicate between scripts.

One simple/crude way of doing what you describe would be to simply have each cooperating script append a line to a file, and the ‘global count’ is the size of this file:

```
#! /bin/sh -
echo ping >>/tmp/scriptcountfile
```

then `wc -l /tmp/scriptcountfile` is the number of times that's happened.  Of course, there's a potential race condition there, so something like the following would sequence those accesses:

```
#! /bin/sh -
(
flock -n 9 
echo 'do stuff...'
echo ping >>/tmp/stampfile
) 9>/tmp/lockfile
```

(the `flock` command is available on Linux, but isn't portable).

Of course, then you can start to do fancier things by having scripts send stuff through pipes and sockets, but that's going somewhat over the top.

Comment: Actually -- `echo >>countfile` shouldn't be racy even without a lock, unless your filesystem is NFS or something else that doesn't correctly implement `O_APPEND`. Opening in `O_APPEND` mode, as `>>` does, means that writes always go straight to the bottom, no matter whether anything else is making concurrent modifications. You need to keep your writes small enough that they don't get split into two syscalls, but making it a single-byte newline append solves that.

Comment: Mind if I steal your approach (append / track size)?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Good point about `O_APPEND` (and thanks: I'd never really internalised that `open(2)` behaviour before).  You're right that this is probably overkill, but it might be useful if the OP is doing something more heavyweight than described.  And re (ii), feel free...